# LongClick event happens too quickly. How can I increase the clicktime required to trigger it?

Tags: android, event-handling

In an application I'm working on, I have the requirement that a user must click & hold a component for a period time before a certain action occurs.

I'm currently using an OnLongClickListener to listen for the longclick, but I find that the length of a click to trigger the OnLongClick event is too short.

For example, let's say the LongClick event triggers after a 400ms click, but I want the user to have to click & hold for 1200ms before the event triggers.

Is there any way I can configure the LongClick event to require a longer click?
Or is there perhaps another construct that would allow me to listen for longer clicks?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is not possible to change the timer on the onLongClick event, it is managed by android itself.

What is possible is to use .setOnTouchListener().

Then register when the MotionEvent is a ACTION_DOWN.
Note the current time in a variable.
Then when a MotionEvent with ACTION_UP is registered and the current_time - actionDown time > 1200 ms then do something.

so pretty much:

```
Button button = new Button();
long then = 0;
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                then = (Long) System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(((Long) System.currentTimeMillis() - then) > 1200){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Comment: This almost does what I need it to do. The posted approach only executes the code when the user lifts their finger. I'd like my business logic to run as soon as the delay is up, rather than when the user stops pressing.

Comment: Why is then = getSystemTime() commented out?

Also getSystemTime() method does not work. Did you mean:
System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: Confirmed. Define then as a long, not an int. Then use: then = (Long) System.currentTimeMillis(); and when finding the difference make sure to again cast to long when using System.currentTimeMillis() instead of getSystemTime()

Answer (score 6):

This is the simplest way that I have found to achieve this behavior. It has a couple of advantages over the currently accepted answer.

1. By checking `view.isPressed` we ensure that the `onClick` and `onLongClick` are not triggered if the touch event leaves the view. This mimics the default `onClick` and `onLongClick` behavior of the system.
2. The event already stores timing information so there is no need to store the start time on `ACTION_DOWN` or calculate the current time on `ACTION_UP` ourselves. This means that we can use it for multiple views at the same time because we aren't tracking the event start time in a single variable outside of `onTouch`.

NOTE: `ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout()` is the default and you can change that check to use any value you want.

NOTE: If the view is not normally clickable you will need to call `view.setClickable(true)` for the `view.isPressed()` check to work.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (view.isPressed() && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        long eventDuration = event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime();
        if (eventDuration > ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout()) {
            onLongClick(view);
        } else {
            onClick(view);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you, like @ampersandre, would like the long click event to trigger immediately once the delay period is reached instead of waiting for `ACTION_UP` then the following works well for me.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        view.setTag(true);
    } else if (view.isPressed() && (boolean) view.getTag()) {
        long eventDuration = event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime();
        if (eventDuration > ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout()) {
            view.setTag(false);
            onLongClick(view);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            onClick(view);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, it was really helpful for me. I have one minor problem with your solution (the long click event to trigger immediately once the delay period is reached one): it needs to have touch events continuously to check if duration > timout. So, if U don't have small movements on the button during it is pressed (move event...), onLongClick triggering can happen later than the timout. Do U have any suggestions? Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I worked out a solution with the help of [Rohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530543/rohan) :)
I adapted his answer to fit my requirements.

When the user pushes the button, a thread is started. The thread sleeps for my desired delay, then when it wakes up, it executes whatever code I need it to do. When the user lets go, the thread is killed. This accomplishes what I want, because if the user lets go before the thread wakes up, the thread is interrupted and the action doesn't occur.

I like this approach because it lets me execute my business logic as soon as the delay is up, which is good because I can give the user some feedback letting them know they've pushed long enough (the phone can vibrate, for example).
The downside to this approach is: there is a risk that the user lets go of the button while your desired action is running, and kills the thread before everything is done. This isn't a huge problem for my case, because my business logic does very little; it just fires an event for some other class to process. If the action didn't complete fully, it's acceptable for the user to have to try again.

The code is a little longer than I'd like, but if this is a common feature in your application, it's easily re-useable. Here's a code example:

```
protected class MyLongClickListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private Thread longClickSensor;

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        // If the user is pressing down and there is no thread, make one and start it
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && longClickSensor == null) {
            longClickSensor = new Thread(new MyDelayedAction());
            longClickSensor.start();
        }
        // If the user has let go and there was a thread, stop it and forget about the thread
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && longClickSensor != null) {
            longClickSensor.interrupt();
            longClickSensor = null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private class MyDelayedAction implements Runnable {
        private final long delayMs = 1200;

        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delayMs); // Sleep for a while
                doBusinessLogic();     // If the thread is still around after the sleep, do the work
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { return; }
        }
        private void doBusinessLogic() {
            // Make sure this logic is as quick as possible, or delegate it to some other class
            // through Broadcasted Intents, because if the user lets go while the work is happenening,
            // the thread will be interrupted.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will get messy, when the user uses a second finger. you should check, if there is already a thread started or you should keep track of the different picker ids.

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple solution studying how the long press event works.
Each time a view is clicked, a `Runnable` of type `CheckForLongPress` is added to a queue with a delay. If the delay ends, the `OnLongClickListener` is called. If there is a different event before the delay ends, then, the `CheckForLongPress Runnable` is removed from de queue.

I just override the public method `postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis)` of the view to change the OS delay

```
@Override public boolean postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis) {
    boolean isLongPress = action.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("CheckForLongPress");
    return super.postDelayed(action, isLongPress ? LONG_PRESS_MILLIS : delayMillis);
}
```

I set `LONG_PRESS_MILLIS` to 100 and it's working!

Hope it helps!!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
final boolean[] isLongPress = {false};
final int duration = 3000;
final Handler someHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable someCall = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isLongPress[0]) {
                // your code goes here 
            }
        }
    };

    someButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int eventAction = event.getAction();
            if(eventAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                isLongPress[0] = true;
                someHandler.postDelayed(someCall, duration);
            }
            else if (eventAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                isLongPress[0] = false;
                someHandler.removeCallbacks(someCall);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` was firing and causing `removeCallbacks`

Answer (score 2):

One method can do it. It's simple to use, easy to configure the time length, on time to trigger the callback.

```
public static void setOnLongClickListener(final View view, final View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener, final long delayMillis)
{
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                longClickListener.onLongClick(view);
                mRunning = false;
            }
        };

        boolean mRunning;
        boolean mOutside;
        RectF mRect = new RectF();

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayMillis);
                    mRunning = true;
                    mOutside = false;
                    mRect.set(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (!mOutside)
                    {
                        mOutside = !mRect.contains(v.getLeft() + event.getX(), v.getTop() + event.getY());
                        if (mOutside)
                        {
                            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                            mRunning = false;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    if (mRunning)
                        v.performClick();
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    mRunning = false;
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    mRunning = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true; // !!!
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this method. It is so simple.

```
private static final long HOLD_PRESS_TIME = 1200; //ms unit    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_control);

    //Declare your button and add listener
    ImageView iconImg = findViewById(R.id.more_icon);
    iconImg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.w("Button", "Button is pressed...");
                    //Start timer
                    timer.start();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.w("Button", "Button is released...");
                    //Clear timer
                    timer.cancel();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


}

private CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(HOLD_PRESS_TIME, 200) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        Log.w("Button", "Count down..."+l); //It call onFinish() when l = 0
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //TODO your action here!
        Log.w("Button", "Count finish...");

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is my implementation :)

```
public abstract class MyLongClickListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private int delay;
    private boolean down;
    private Runnable callback;
    private RectF mRect = new RectF();

    public MyLongClickListener(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
        this.callback = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                down = false;
                onLongClick();
            }
        };
    }

    public abstract void onLongClick();

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getPointerCount() > 1) return true;

        int action = e.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            down = true;
            mRect.set(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
            v.postDelayed(callback, delay);
            return false;

        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (down && !mRect.contains(v.getLeft() + e.getX(), v.getTop() + e.getY())) {
                v.removeCallbacks(callback);
                down = false;
                return false;
            }

        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (down) {
                v.removeCallbacks(callback);
                v.performClick();
            }
            return true;

        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            v.removeCallbacks(callback);
            down = false;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

---

Usage:

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new MyLongClickListener(2000) {
    @Override
    public void onLongClick() {
        System.err.println("onLongClick");
    }
});
```