# Android how to use both OnClick and Long press(3 sec) for same Button

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

In my `application` I need to do some `Action A` while doing normal `click` for the `button` and also need to do some other `Action B` while holding the same button for more than `3` sec.
I have tried this below code

```
private boolean isMoved = false;
    final Runnable runr = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Your code to run on long click
                        System.out.println("long pressed for 3 sec");

                    }
                };

                final Handler handel = new Handler();
                contactButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                        switch (arg1.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            isMoved = false;
                            handel.postDelayed(runr,3000);
                            break;          
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            isMoved = true;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            if(!isMoved)
                                System.out.println("button single click");

                        default:
                            handel.removeCallbacks(runr);
                            break;

                        }
                        return true;

                    }
                });
```

But it is not working like what I expect,anyone please guide me to complete this operation.

Comment: Advise: Don't use ``System.out.println`` use Log

Comment: @zhelon Sure, I will

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934245/longclick-event-happens-too-quickly-how-can-i-increase-the-clicktime-required-t

Answer (score 3):

Jamal.
You really need to wait for 3 secs?

If you don't need to wait for 3 secs, use the methods setOnClickListener for single click actions, and setOnLongClickListener for long click actions.

You can check it out in the following links:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)

--

In the case you really need to wait for 3 secs, you have to check the difference between the timestamp of the ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN.

---

EDIT:

```
public class YourClass {    
private MotionEvent mLastEvent = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;

final Runnable runr = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(mLastEvent == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                            // Your code to run on long click
                        }
                    }
                };

final Handler handel = new Handler();
contactButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        mLastEvent = arg1.getAction();
        switch (arg1.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    handel.postDelayed(runr,3000);
                    break;          
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                default:
                    handel.removeCallbacks(runr);
                    break;

            }
                return true;
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Yes, I need to do a long press with 3 sec only. not a default Android `Longclick`

Comment: So instead of using a handler, store the time associated to the ACTION_DOWN event and when the ACTION_UP is triggered, check the difference between them. If it's more than or equals to 3 secs you can consider as a long click event.

Comment: Your solution is good, whether is it any possibility for triggering operation when button holding reaches 3 sec.means doing some work when time interval reaches 3 sec. as per your solution it will calculate the time interval when user took his finger.So if user tapping the button more than 3 sec(ex 10 sec) it won't do any operation until he removes his finger.

Answer (score 3):

All answers and comments are true. Here is your implementation

```
Button button;
long down,up;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    down=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    up=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if(up-down>3000)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "More than 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is extension function for Kotlin. Basically, you pass two lambdas: one for normal click, 1 for click longer than 3 secs. Gathered solutions here and there

```
fun View.setCustomClickListeners(
onVeryLongClick: () -> Unit,
onNormalClick: () -> Unit
) {
setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {

    private val longClickDuration = 3000L
    private var lastTouchEventTime: Long = 0L
    private val handler = Handler()

    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            lastTouchEventTime = Date().time
           //for state when pressed optional
            v?.foreground = v?.context?.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_selectable_transparent)
            handler.postDelayed({ onVeryLongClick.invoke() }, longClickDuration)
        }
        else if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(Date().time  - lastTouchEventTime < longClickDuration){
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                onNormalClick.invoke()
            }
            //restore foreground when view is no longer being pressed
            v?.foreground = null
        }
        return true
    }
})
```

}