# How to handle the longclick in android

Tags: java, android

I want to make a layout visible by using long click, and invisible by clicking again, it is not working for me.
please help me with this.
The code is given below.
when I click once the layout is visible when I click again the layout need to be gone, but still it is visible.

```
     public class ReminderstestExplaination extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView testexplntion_recycle;
    CustomRecyclerview customRecyclerview;
    LinearLayout reminderpage_addbutton,extraremlay,del_editlay;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remindertest_explaination,container,false);

        extraremlay = v.findViewById (R.id.extraremlay);

        extraremlay.setOnLongClickListener (new View.OnLongClickListener () {
                                                @Override
                                                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                                                    del_editlay.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);

                                                    return true;

                                                }
                                            });
}
```

Comment: Please attach the XML and full code of your Fragment

Comment: you have to debug it to know why it is not working

Comment: You need the code to become visible by long click, and invisible by another long click or a normal click? Your current `OnLongClickListener` only sets visibility to true. If you want to toggle both states using long click, you need an `if` condition there.

Comment: looks like you are working with hide/show in recyclerview, can you try to create sample activity with a button and view and try the same code with them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597203/android-how-to-use-both-onclick-and-long-press3-sec-for-same-button - Please check this link, this might helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this , keep track of the visibility using a boolean variable and change it every time long click is done.

```
public class ReminderstestExplaination extends Fragment {
boolean isVisible = false;
RecyclerView testexplntion_recycle;
CustomRecyclerview customRecyclerview;
LinearLayout reminderpage_addbutton,extraremlay,del_editlay;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remindertest_explaination,container,false);

    extraremlay = v.findViewById (R.id.extraremlay);

    extraremlay.setOnLongClickListener (new View.OnLongClickListener () {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                                               if(isVisible) {
                                                isVisible = false;
                                               del_editlay.setVisibility 
                                              (View.INVISIBLE);
                                              }
                                               }
                                               else {
                                             isVisible = true;
                                             del_editlay.setVisibility 
                                              (View.VISIBLE);}

                                                return true;

                                            }
                                        });
```

}

Comment: I suppose `del_editlay.getVisibility()` or `del_editlay.isShown()` could be used instead of maintaining a boolean?