# Check end of long click in listview - Android

Tags: android, listview

I have got question. In my *list view* (*lv*) i have method for catching **clicks** on items in it and **long clicks**.

- On click on item, new intent opens. That is working fine.
- then I have long click listener, on long click the long text in textview starts scrolling (*marquee*). But i can't detect, when user stops holding the item, to stop moving the text.

***My code:*** (I must it set in java, becaause in xml it isn't working)

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
    arg1.findViewById(R.id.jmenoskoly);
    TV = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.jmenoskoly);
    TV.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    TV.setSingleLine(true);
    TV.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(5);
    TV.setSelected(true);

    return true;
  }

});
```

So my question is: ***How to check if user stopped holding the item in listview?*** (Please full code example.)

Comment: [have tried to measure how long user holds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934245/longclick-event-happens-too-quickly-how-can-i-increase-the-clicktime-required-t) `onItemLongClick` fires once after fixed delay, not related to users motion, which you want to track

Comment: I want to detect if user pick up his finger. (From listview item or screen = same result.)

Comment: TouchListener tracks both down and up states but you may have to implement a custom adapter to set one on each item.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Adapter class with a TouchListener. You can start the marquee on the down action and stop it on the up action:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mItems; // However you want to store your data

    private static class ViewHolder{
        // Put the views you want to interact with here
        TextView textView;

        ViewHolder(View view){
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items){
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position){
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    public void add(String item){
        mItems.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        // You don't have to use the ViewHolder pattern but it's meant to
        // optimize performance
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                    .inflate(R.layout.my_item_layout, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Set the values of your views
        viewHolder.textView.setText(mItems.get(position));

        // Set your listener on the desired view
        viewHolder.textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Do something on the down action
                        return true; // Consume the action

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Do something on the up action
                        return true; // Consume the action
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity:

```
// Create a new instance of your custom Adapter
// passing in the Context and item values
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, myItems);
listview.setAdapter(adapter); // Attach Adapter to ListView
```