# Checking if button is held for a duration or if it is just clicked ANDROID

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to do something pretty simple, but for some reason I can't get it to work.
I have two circular buttons.

-When I simply click the top (green) button, I want the buttons to switch colors and remain that way.

-If I HOLD a button for 2 seconds, I want the colors to swap for as long as I hold the button, but then revert back to their original colors as soon as I let go.

I am trying to use an OnClickListener. I am using a switch with 2 cases: MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. (see code below)

To get the duration the button is being held, I use System.currentTimeMillis() within a while loop (while button is being held) --> (if timeElapsed > 2000){switch the colors}

full code below:

```
    greenbutton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
                        if (elapsedTime > 500) {
                            if (switched) {
                                revertButtons();
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                switchButtons();
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    if (switched) {
                        revertButtons();
                        elapsedTime = 0;
                        currentTime = 0;
                        startTime = 0;
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        switchButtons();
                        elapsedTime = 0;
                        currentTime = 0;
                        startTime = 0;
                        return true;
                    }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What issue you are having? the code doesn't work or you or you getting any exceptions or error?

Comment: The code works for clicks, however there is a pause in the UI. i have a animated background, and when I click, that animation pauses for a moment. Also, when I hold the button for a long time, nothing happens.

Comment: Check the answers

Comment: You have to set onTouchListener for that button . and stop|start timer between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the predefined methods -

1. `onClickListener( () => {} )` for single clicks
2. `onLongClickListener( () => {} )` for long clicks

This way you don't need to calculate the time the user clicked and by running a loop or thread you may keep changing colours on long clicks.

**UPDATED**

As mentioned in comment its needed only a particular timing use the following algorithm-

1. Start a timer on long click of button
2. As soon as 2 seconds pass you apply your result

** UPDATED**

As the time of click is required follow :

1. Create a timer before button definition
2. Start timer with the long click lister
3. On action up stop timer and you get your result

Comment: I thought about that, but I need to measure that the button is being held for EXACTLY 2 seconds before the colors switch. I couldn't figure out how to do that with onLongClickListener. I also don't know how to revert the colors when the button is let go with onLongClickListener() which is the main thing.

Comment: But the result will be applied regardless if I actually held the button for 2 full seconds or if I just triggered the onLongClickListener() with a shorter duration. There is no way to check when the button is being released, is there?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution studying how the long press event works.
Each time a view is clicked, a `Runnable` of type `CheckForLongPress` is added to a queue with a delay. If the delay ends, the `OnLongClickListener` is called. If there is a different event before the delay ends, then, the `CheckForLongPress Runnable` is removed from de queue.

I just override the public method `postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis)` of the view to change the OS delay

```
@Override public boolean postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis) {
    boolean isLongPress = action.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("CheckForLongPress");
    return super.postDelayed(action, isLongPress ? LONG_PRESS_MILLIS : delayMillis);
}
```

I set `LONG_PRESS_MILLIS` to 100 and it's working!

Hope it helps!!! ;)

**Credit:** [MArtinCR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269857/11233871)

Comment: I like this idea, but how can I check when the button is being released? I can get the buttons to switch if the button is being held for 2 seconds with your code, but when I release the button, I want the colors to revert back. How can I check for this release with OnLongClickListener?