# How to add onClickListener for a button after keep clicking on it for a while?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

Hi guys i'm a beginner android dev and i have a question that i didn't find it answer yet. I want to add an onClickListener for a Button after keep clicking on it for 1.5 seconds for example?

Comment: You could use the `setOnLongClickListener` method if you need a delayed event handler. If you need to set your interval precisely you could use a custom `setOnTouchListener`. Can you be more specific with your question and add some of your code to it so that we can help you?

Comment: Thank u for ur answer, u'll understand me better if use instagram, for example when u click on a message it opens a new activity but when u keep clicking on it for a period of time Without pulling your hand out of it u get a dialog that has a lots of options( delete conversation, block ....)

Comment: looks like you want to say that if you long press a button for a duration of time this happens , either you can use `View.OnLongClickListener` or as you said of 1.5 seconds you can custom define the time limit as shown in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Originally Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7934585/11002756)

You can't define custom duration for `onLongClickListener()`
Rather you should use onTouchListener and see the time when the user clicked on the button
and when that time surpassed your limit do your code like this

```
Button your_button = findViewById(R.id.your_button_ID);
long time = 0;
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                time = (Long) System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(((Long) System.currentTimeMillis() - time) > 1500){
 // if time>1.5 seconds do your code here

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the explanation :)

Comment: does this works for you?

Comment: yeah thank u, i'm using kotlin for developing android apps so i convert the code that u send me and it works

Comment: @Pan Ix okay i did thanks