# How To Use OnTouchListener To Open New Activity

Tags: java, android

I Tried OnClickListener an OnLongClickListener And yea it worked but those are too quick and i want to make them even more longer and i am just unable to use OntouchListener To Open New Activity And i have no clue almost tried everything nothing worked

**Activity Name: Website**

**Button id: action_button (its a floatingActionbutton)**

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
            FloatingActionButton actionButton = findViewById(R.id.action_button);
    
            defineView();
            handleIntent();
            defineActionBar();
            checkPermission();
                      
                       //i tried both here 
    
    
        public void openWebsite() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Website.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what behavior you are trying to get from `onTouchListener` and how it is different from just using `onClickListener`?

Comment: Yes Both Are different we cant control time in OnLongClickListener but we can do this In OnTouchListener

Comment: So put - *specifically* - what you want to do in the question. "Control time" is not specific. Here's an example "I want the user to go to the web page after holding the button down for 1.5 seconds".

Comment: Also, have you tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934245/longclick-event-happens-too-quickly-how-can-i-increase-the-clicktime-required-t)? You should probably also consider whether it will be confusing for your app's users to have some custom long-click behavior in your app that is different from "standard android long clicks". Usually it is much better for usability to stick with convention so your app behaves in a way that is consistent with other android programs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to use OnTouchListener instead of OnClickListener since I don't think there is any difference between them referring to button events.

whit OnClickListener you could capture long press with:

```
    button.setOnLongClickListener {
        //ACTION
        
        true
    }
```

EDIT: (for custom duration, you should use OnTouchListener, thats right)

you can do something like this:

```
  long time = 0;

  button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
       if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
       }
       else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            double duration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - time / 1000.0);
            if(duration > 5){
                action2();
                return true;
            }else if(duration > 3.2){
                action1();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
        }
   });
```

Comment: Dude There is difference we cant control the holding duration in OnLongClickListener . can i?

Comment: @Xtra514 you are right OnTouchListener is needed for custome holding duration. Have a look at my answer now.